# How to mock class with @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, springmockito

I have a class that Autowires another class with @ConfigurationProperties.

#### Class with @ConfigurationProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "report")
public class SomeProperties {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
...
```

#### Class that Autowires above class SomeProperties

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SomeService {
    ....
    @Autowired
    private SomeProperties someProperties;
    .... // There are other things
```

Now, I want to test **SomeService** class and in my test class when I mock **SomeProperties** class, I am getting `null` value for all the properties.

#### Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SomeProperties.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    @Mock // I tried @MockBean as well, it did not work
    private SomeProperties someProperties;
```

How can I mock **SomeProperties** having properties from `application-test.properties` file.

Comment: Use constructor injection, not field injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not mocking SomeProperties if you intend to bind values from a properties file, in which case an actual instance of SomeProperties would be provided.

Mock:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeService someService;

    @Mock
    private SomeProperties someProperties;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        // you need to provide a return behavior whenever someProperties methods/props are invoked in someService
        when(someProperties.getProperty1()).thenReturn(...)
    }
```

No Mock (`someProperties` is an real object that binds its values from some propertysource):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SomeServiceTest {
   
    private SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    private SomeProperties someProperties;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        someService = new someService(someProperties); // Constructor Injection
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Do we need constructor injection for the autowired property

Comment: @12kadir12 What''s being `@Autowired` here doesn't have dependency on other Beans. So no. But in the case where dependency beans are present in the `@Autowired` bean, you could mock the dependency beans with @MockBean and provide stubbing for them.

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work, the only difference is that I am using the .yml file instead of the properties file. Maybe the spring boot version is old since the project is legacy :) Do you have any idea?

Comment: @12kadir12 the reason is *@TestPropertySource* does not support YAML property files. Instead of this annotation you have provide special initializer via *@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)* or ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class if you're using Spring Boot older than 2.4.

Comment: @NikitaKobtsev thank you for the explanation. I changed my yaml property files with original ones. but now, i know why i couldn't use @ TestPropertySource  :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to stub all the property values in @Test/@Before methods of SomeServiceTest.java like :

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(someProperties, "property1", "value1");

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(object, name, value);
```

You can also mock the reponse for dependent classes via Mockito.when()

Answer (score 1):

If you are using @Mock , you need to stub the values as well. By default the value will be null for all the properties.